# Season system Implementation system in unity

Tags: unity

So I am planning on implementing a seasons system for a 2D top-down game. Each season will have a characteristic terrain feature e.g. summers will have patches of grass spread out .. which I wanna reproduce by green bloat spread around on a 2D plane or quad...  These features will need to generate dynamically for every season. The implementation will be simplistic nonetheless... using green bloats for grass patches, blue bloats for waterholes.. Can you guys give me like pointers to solve this problem?

Some Reference images:-

1. Notice how the backdrop/background changes for each season
2. Green Patches denotes grass
3. Light blue denotes unfrozen water, dark blue denotes frozen water
4. These bloats are to be generated dynamically, with some conditions like frozen water and unfrozen water need to spawn next to each other

### Summer Season ##[image: Summer Season]## Monsoon Season ##[image: Monsoon season]## Winter Season ##[image: Winter season]

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with and what result do you want to achieve, are there any reference images?

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ I updated the question with reference images

Comment: Do you want these to be one generated sprite, or tiles, or separate sprites from predefined ones?

Comment: I think seperately generated sprite will be good.. So my gameObjects can actually interact with it.

Comment: You need to decide what way you want to do it. Either by generating the mesh for sprites and applying color. Or having predefined sprites. Also, you will need to position your objects depending on your project needs. There are many ways to procedurally generate something. You can use gradient noise or any other... Or you can define your own logic to spawn objects. It's very broad topic. https://www.youtube.com/user/Cercopithecan/featured has a lot of good tutorials specifically on procedural generation.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ thanks for sharing the youtube link.. I will definitely check it out